# Composer uses own Symfony path in docker (loading old files)

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, docker, composer-php

- I'm using docker.
- Post update command (php class) is running after composer update.
- Was working well till I did Laravel update 5.4->5.5 which downloaded new Symfony packages
- composer clear cache didn't help
- composer self-update didn't help
- composer signatures are equal

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]   Call to
>   undefined method
>   Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ClosureCommand::setHidden()

I was serching the files and this method exist in parent class! I put this little thing in constructor what is going on:

```
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command as SymfonyCommand;

class Command extends SymfonyCommand
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $r1 = new \ReflectionClass($this);
        $r2 = new \ReflectionClass(SymfonyCommand::class);
        var_dump([$r1->getFileName(), $r2->getFileName()]);
    }
// rest of class
}
```

Result: composer autoload own, older Command.php instead of this from project.

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(91) "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/ClosureCommand.php"
  [1]=>
  string(67) "phar:///usr/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php"
}
```

**I would like to know why symfony class is not loaded from project but from some magic place and how I can fix that.**

---

Additional info:

Dockerfile for php that add composer:

```
# Composer
ENV PATH "/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER 1
ENV COMPOSER_HOME /composer
ENV COMPOSER_VERSION 1.4.2

RUN curl -s -f -L -o /tmp/composer-setup.php https://getcomposer.org/installer
RUN curl -s -f -L -o /tmp/composer-setup.sig https://composer.github.io/installer.sig
RUN php -r " \
    \$signature_php = hash('SHA384', file_get_contents('/tmp/composer-setup.php')); \
    \$signature_sig = trim(file_get_contents('/tmp/composer-setup.sig')); \
    echo ' SIGNATURE PHP: [' . \$signature_php . \"]\\n\"; \
    echo ' SIGNATURE SIG: [' . \$signature_sig . \"]\\n\"; \
    if (\$signature_php !== \$signature_sig) { \
        unlink('/tmp/composer-setup.php'); \
        echo 'Integrity check failed, installer is either corrupt or worse.' . PHP_EOL; \
        exit(1); \
    }"
RUN php /tmp/composer-setup.php --no-ansi --install-dir=/usr/bin cd --filename=composer --version=${COMPOSER_VERSION} \
 && rm /tmp/composer-setup.php \
 && composer --ansi --version --no-interaction
```

Composer part:

```
"post-update-cmd": [
   "Modules\\Core\\Composer\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
   "php artisan vendor:publish --tag=public --force",
   "php artisan optimize"
],
```

Comment: When did the error occur?

Comment: executing via `composer update` or `composer post-update-cmd` which contains script that build Laravel application.

Comment: what does `composer diagnose` say?

Comment: that everything is ok https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/6738

Comment: how does your post-update-cmd look in your composer.json file?

Comment: You have full `composer.json` file under above link. I also added this part it in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the signature for obtain composer is not matching, you have to know that signature can change, if you want to obtain the last one use this url https://composer.github.io/installer.sig

Use this snippet for verify signature.

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');" && \
            php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === '$(wget -q -O - https://composer.github.io/installer.sig)') { \
                echo 'Installer good'; \
            } else { \
                echo 'Installer corrupt'; die; \
            } echo PHP_EOL;"
```

Comment: Thank you for your code. I did change my to something similar. Signatures are equal.

SIGNATURE PHP: [544e09ee996cdf60ece3804abc52599c22b1f40f4323403c44d44fdfdd586475ca9813a858088ffbc1f233e9b180f061]
 SIGNATURE SIG: [544e09ee996cdf60ece3804abc52599c22b1f40f4323403c44d44fdfdd586475ca9813a858088ffbc1f233e9b180f061]

Answer (score 1):

I think that running `composer self-update` command updates the composer's signature as well. Also i would suggest try the following if you have ssh access to the server:

- Remove `composer.lock`.
- Remove `vendor` folder.
- Run `composer install`

This should fix all the issues you mentioned.

Comment: This was one of the first things I did. I could even delete `symfony console package` and error would occur because `composer` somehow stores its own version of this package, not compatible with one `Laravel 5.5` uses. Whats more funny, all of this stand on docker, so building containers from scratch should wipe all cache. I feel like I tried everything :/

Answer (score 1):

this is how I install composer (Alpine, php7.1-fpm, self compiled nginx)

```
EXPECTED_COMPOSER_SIGNATURE=$(wget -q -O - https://composer.github.io/installer.sig) && \
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');" && \
php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === '${EXPECTED_COMPOSER_SIGNATURE}') { echo 'Composer.phar Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Composer.phar Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;" && \
php composer-setup.php --install-dir=/usr/bin --filename=composer && \
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

and try to change your post-install to this (laravel 5.5, dockerized and smoothly running)

```
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
        "php artisan optimize"
         .....
```

Comment: Of course this will run with no problem, as oryginal `ComposerScripts` doesn't create application. I have my own scripts that use current env settings. Bootstraping application from script is enough to trigger error. My friends, I strongly believe it's composer loading own files instead of projects problem (cached or maybe included in composer package).

Comment: Just to rule out every possibility... Can you provide your own ComposerScripts Class ?

Comment: try to call "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate" first, your script will still make the needed changes. and did you put your "service provider" line in config/app.php ?